# Deciding to WSGI or Django for new web app

Tags: python, django, wsgi, django-wsgi

I'm in the process of setting up a new web app and deciding whether to just do it with WSGI or go the full framework route with Django.

The app's foremost requirements:

1) The app has no UI what so ever and all of the data is exposed to clients via a REST api with JSON.

2) It will have data to persist so MongoDB & probably Amazon's SimpleDB will be used for the database side.

Is there a reason to use Django or can I get marginal speed improvement with WSGI only?

Previous server-side apps I've built were either with Java/Struts and Groovy/Grails on the JVM. My understanding is that Django is an MVC framework similar to Rails and Grails.

I've also played around with Google App Engine which uses WSGI as thin layer above your code for managing and routing requests.

Answer (score 7):

I suggest you consider something between those two extremes.  [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/) is lightweight, very easy to use, and connects to your web server via wsgi.  You can use regular python database connectors with it, and a few databases even have Flask-specific [extension](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/extensions/) modules.

Comment: wsgi contains too much burden. Flask will clear that point, and just get out your way and it seems that is just what you need.

Comment: @Ahmet "wsgi contains too much burden. Flask will clear that point," what the heck is that supposed to mean?

Comment: I think Ahmet means that writing an application atop Flask is easier than writing directly to WSGI. That is true and entirely expected, since WSGI was designed as a minimal interface for application frameworks, not for the applications themselves.

Answer (score 0):

I have worked with Django for a couple of projects and I like it a lot, but since you are going to use **mongoDB** and a lot of **JSON** I suggest you use **NodeJS** as server side, with **Express** as framework, you can see a brief tutorial here:

http://howtonode.org/express-mongodb

One of the advantages of this is that you will use **only javascript** all along your project, I began working with this technology the last month in a Hackathon, and I can tell you that I'm very impressed of how fast and simple it is.

Answer (score 0):

I've worked a bit with some django "apps" ,its really easy, but setting up the "apps" can be a bit of a long process.  Django has a lot of nice features that you won't be using and I agree that you might be on one "extreme" here.